# Encrypting a MailBox Server Side

Tags: email, dovecot

So I am not even sure if this is possible but I figured this would be the best place to ask. I have a dovecot server that I use for receiving mail , the mail is stored in a Maildir format.

Is there a way for me to encrypt the mail so that if someone get access to the server they wont be able to read the mail ?

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot needs to access the mails unencrypted.
What can help you here is disk encyption. You can store all your data encrypted on the disk. So the password is needed to access the data. You provide it during boot and you are good to go otherwise it is unavailable.

**DO Backups!**

To set up encryption:

```
crytsetup luksFormat /dev/somedevice
```

Then make it accessible:

```
crytsetup luksOpen /dev/somedevice unencrypted_device
```

Now you can format then mount `/dev/mapper/unencrypted_device` as usual.
If you want to automate the boot process or set up full encryption (for the root disk) read your distro's manual.

Comment: Thanks , but I am a little past this point atm